# Unix/linux shell scripting floating point division

Tags: bash, unix, shell, bash-scripting

I have to divide two floating point values and store it in variable. 
My code below

`v_missedvol=4003.03
 v_allvolume=3003.03
v_vol_temp= $(echo "$v_missedvol  / $v_allvolume" | bc -l )`

the result that I get is

```
-ksh: =1.33299700635691285135: not found [No such file or directory]
```

further , I need the value to be stored as

```
v_volume_total=1.3329 *100
```

Please help with this , Thanks !

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with the last line. Do you need to store the result of `1.3329*100`? do you need to truncate the result before multiplication? Do you want to store the actual formula "1.3329 *100"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small syntax error. there may be no space between `v_vol_tem=` and `$(echo ...`

try

```
v_vol_temp=$(echo "$v_missedvol / $v_allvolume" | bc -l )
```

Comment: @VIGNESH12990 if the answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Or just use the floating point support built into ksh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
v_missedvol=4003.03
v_allvolume=3003.03
v_vol_temp=$(( v_missedvol  / v_allvolume ))
echo $v_vol_temp
```